# how to remove spam comments from pending list in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Our WordPress site has more than 20,000 pending comments which are majorly spam. We already have the Akismet plugin to filter spam but it seems that the majority of the spam is not being caught. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to filter the pending comments for spam?

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to your cPanel or other Control Panel
2. Select your database
3. Click the SQL tab and run the following command:

`DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = '0'`